# Admin login redirect error, on Debian Owncloud install

Tags: php, apache, owncloud

I made an install of Owncloud on my Debian 8 server by follow the guide (https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/owncloud/index.html):

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/production/Debian_9.0/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/production/Debian_9.0/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud-files
```

Then, I move the default /var/www/owncloud folder into /var/www/**html**/owncloud and I complete the installation.

But now, when I login in with my admin account, owncloud seems to can't redirect me to my default page account. It stay on the login page. The password is correct because when I log in with a wrong password, I got the message "Wrong Password, reset it ?"

The url is:

```
myServerIp/owncloud/index.php/login?redirect_url=%252Fowncloud%252Findex.php%252Fapps%252Ffiles%252F
```

So what's wrong ? Is there a problem because of the move of /var/www/owncloud folder into /var/www/**html**/owncloud ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.
My password was too strong, with special caracters.
I put an easy password, then I changed to a strong one in the admin panel.